# How to fit the curve that this lines made? The length of lines are all fixed

Tags: graphics, geometry

[image]

[image]

but how to deduce it ?
Thank you .

Comment: For the record, this is the forum for the software *Mathematica*, you were probably looking for math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)

Comment: I don't think your lines on above illustrations are actually equal-length, since they seem to be from $(0, a)$ to $(1-a, 0)$.

Answer (score 9):

It's an [astroid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Astroid.html) and not a circle. In any event:

```
With[{r = 1, n = 30}, 
     Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[1], 
               Table[Line[r {{Cos[θ], 0}, {0, Sin[θ]}}], {θ, 0, π/2, π/(2 n)}]}]]
```

[image: astroid as envelope]

A short proof that the astroid is the correct envelope:

```
{x, InterpolatingPolynomial[{{Cos[θ], 0}, {0, Sin[θ]}}, x]} /.
    First[Solve[D[InterpolatingPolynomial[{{Cos[θ], 0}, {0, Sin[θ]}}, x], θ] == 0, x]]
    // FullSimplify
```

Comment: Fair enough, I'm too trusting with what people claim to know.

Comment: great! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Based on your image, but not your statement on lengths of lines:

```
With[{eqn = a - a x / (1 - a)},
 Show[
  Quiet@Plot[Table[eqn, {a, 0, 1, 1 / 20}], {x, 0, 1},
   Evaluated -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {0, 1},
   PlotStyle -> Gray],
  Plot[MaxValue[{eqn, 0 <= a <= 1}, a], {x, 0, 1},
   Evaluated -> True, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]]]
```

[image]

For the intended plot your can replace `eqn` with the following:

```
eqn = Sin[Pi a / 2] - Tan[Pi a / 2] x
```

[image]

Comment: `Solve[{#, D[#, a]} &[x/a + y/(1 - a) == 1], {x, y}, {a}]` also yields the red parabola (`1 + (x - y)^2 - 2 (x + y)`).

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{1-x^{2/3}}-\sqrt{1-x^{2/3}}x^{2/3}$$

```
Plot[Sqrt[1 - x^(2/3)] - Sqrt[1 - x^(2/3)] x^(2/3), {x, 0, 1}, 
AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red, Dashed}
```

[image]